# Stackalloc Pointer to Pointer in C#

Tags: c#, memory, libsvm

I have a structue like this in c#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct svm_node
{
    internal int index;
    internal double value;
}
```

and I wrote the below code to allocate unmanaged memory to variable p

```
svm_node** p = stackalloc svm_node*[100];
```

but after executing the code the variable p is null, but if I use this code:

```
svm_node* p = stackalloc svm_node[100];
```

p will be a real pointer.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me too: `svm_node** p = stackalloc svm_node*[100]; *p = (svm_node*)(new IntPtr(42)); Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", (IntPtr)p, (IntPtr)(*p));`

Comment: stackalloc *never* returns null, guaranteed.  The simplest explanation is that you discovered that the dereferenced pointers are all null.  That's by design, stackalloc zero-initializes the allocated memory.  Or to put it another way, you merely allocated pointers, no structures at all.  That is not very practical.

Comment: Too many thanks to all, I have another problem and that's can I allocate a memory in a function and don't loose it when I returned from that func? stackalloc memory will be freed by after returning from a function.